# Azure WebJobs in local development environment UseDevelopmentStorage=true

Tags: .net, azure, asp.net-core, azure-webjobs

```
 "AzureWebJobsDashboard": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
 "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true"
```

Getting error

The listener for function 'WebJobsMethods.UpdateFreeTrialStatus' was unable to start.
Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Listeners.FunctionListenerException: The listener for function 'WebJobsMethods.UpdateFreeTrialStatus' was unable to start. ---> Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.StorageException: An error occurred while sending the request. ---> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request. ---> System.Net.Http.WinHttpException: A connection with the server could not be established

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to start the Azure Storage Emulator to use this connection string.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-emulator

Comment: Just to make sure: Did you explicitly start the emulator? It does not run by default.

Comment: Thanks didn't know about that.

Comment: Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer solved your issue, please mark it as accepted by clicking the green check mark. This helps keep the focus on older SO which still don't have answers.